# Impact of a 5th fundamental force discovery

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces, gravity, newtonian-gravity

Recently released paper that hints to a fifth fundamental force  https://astronomynow.com/2016/08/16/fifth-force-of-nature-could-be-key-to-understanding-dark-matter/

> The UCI work demonstrates that instead of being a dark photon, the particle may be a “protophobic X boson.” While the normal electric force acts on electrons and protons, this newfound boson interacts only with electrons and neutrons — and at an extremely limited range. Analysis co-author Timothy Tait, professor of physics & astronomy, said, “There’s no other boson that we’ve observed that has this same characteristic. Sometimes we also just call it the ‘X boson,’ where ‘X’ means unknown.”

I'm trying to get a gauge on what this discovery (if true) would imply to our current understanding of particle physics and which discipline within physics would the impact be seen the most.

Also of interest, would this force be strong enough to have an effect on the standard GMm/r^2 formula (IE it would now be GMm/r^2 + newforce)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the "protophobic fifth force" observed in nuclear decays a new fundamental force?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258214/)

Comment: First question of mine is duplicate.   second question not so much.   I wonder why I couldn't find that duplicate question when I searched for 5th fundamental force on here.

Comment: The search function on StackExchange is pretty bad. It probably couldn't figure out '5th' was the same as 'fifth'.

Comment: If you feel your question is partly but not entirely a duplicate, you should edit out the duplicate part and emphasize the new part.

Comment: Heh, you posted that comment while I was editting the question.   And yes, I think you are right, the fifth vs 5th makes a diff.