# Do axions have an anti-particle?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, antimatter, axion

Axions are the particles that let energy flash between a matter particle and its anti-particle. But according to quantum field theory, every particle has an anti-particle (besides the majorana fermion). So if axions have an anti-particle, why don't they react?

By the way, I am a very smart middle schooler.

Comment: I suggest that you be more considerate towards physicists who spend time explaining something to you - I refer to anna v's explanation which you dismissed, while clearly not understanding what she wrote.

Answer (score 4):

The axion is a *hypothetical* particle; no axion has been observed.  (Neither have any particle-antiparticle oscillations.)  Since we don't know the quantum numbers of any axion, we don't know whether they are distinct from their antiparticles or not.

I'm pretty sure that most models of the axion don't have any quantum numbers which would change sign under the charge-conjugation operation, which converts particles to antiparticles.  Such an axion would, like the photon and the $Z^0$, be its own antiparticle.

Comment: Dude axions exist breh

Comment: Citation needed. If you're thinking about the recent news stories about a possible discovery experiment, you might read my discussion of those results in response to [this other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258214/44126). The status of the axion is not as simple as "dude breh."

Comment: @mithusengupta123 I don't know what a "PQ charge" is.  Axions would have zero electric charge, but one model for the axion is that it's the lowest-mass supersymmetric particle, and the many supersymmetric particles are distinguished by their own sets of quantum numbers.  That's probably a better topic for a follow-up question than for a comment discussion.

Comment: @rob Doesn't axions of QCD hypothesized to solve the strong CP problem come from $U(1)$ Peccei-Quinn (PQ) symmetry breaking?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 I don't know that I've heard about Peccei-Quinn symmetry breaking.  (I'm more of a nuclear person than an axion person, and I've had low research engagement for a few years.)  If there's a quantum number associated with that symmetry which would make a probable model for an axion be *not* its own antiparticle, consider writing a more correct answer to this question, or proposing an edit to mine.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't help pointing out three issues with this answer. 1. The first paragraph would normally be irrelevant; questions about properties of hypothetical particles are totally fine as long as they can be answered through the theory that introduced them; no experimental verification is needed for answering them. 2. The lowest-mass susy particle is *definitely not* related to axion by any theory or theorist. Please reconsider. 3. With all due respect, if you haven't heard about PQ symmetry breaking then starting an answer with "I'm pretty sure" is definitely honest, but not solid.

Comment: @Helen Thanks! It sounds like you are in a position to write an answer that I would learn from. I look forward to reading it.

Comment: I wish I find the time in the next days to do so competently!

Answer (score 3):

Rob's answer is giving the correct physics, but since you are a "smart middle schooler" I would like to address the rest of your question. To start with it will be good to increase your background on axions by reading the [wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion#Prediction) , for encyclopedic information.

> Axions are the particles that let energy flash between a matter particle and its anti-particle.

In particle physics very strict mathematical rules describe the interactions between particles. Particles are on the same status as antiparticles and nothing particular "flashes" unless there is an interaction. Interaction means energy and momentum is exchanged. Usually particles and antiparticles annihilate when they interact, and a plethora of [Feynman diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) describes pictorially the mathematics of their interaction.

> But according to quantum field theory, every particle has an anti-particle (besides the majorana fermion).

Particles can be antiparticles of themselves, as for example the photon. In general bosons are antiparticles of themselves if they are neutral, and the axion is neutral.

> So if axions have an anti-particle, why don't they react?

Interactions happen with energy and momentum exchanges between particles, and theory up to now can predict the probability of various interaction products coming out using field theory and the Feynman diagrams. The existence of antiparticles does not have anything to do with interactions, which need energy and momentum to happen.

In some theories, if the axion has mass it can decay into photons , the energy supplied by its mass.

This is a [Feynman diagram](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Feynman-diagram-of-axion-decay-into-photons-a-The-conversion-in-vacuum-b-The-inverse_fig1_311925873) for an axion interaction with a magnetic field, that can allow calculating the probability of this happening within a specific theoretical model:

[image: axion inter]

Here [is the decay,](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March06/Overduin/Overduin6.html) where the mass of the axion provides the energy.

[image: ax decay]

One can then run an experiment trying to detect photons that could be attributed to axion  interactions and decays.

Maybe your *flashing* statement refers to vacuum loop feynman diagrams . Those diagrams cannot exist by themselves, they need an input energy and momentum, they are higher order (much smaller probability) Feynman diagrams that have to be added to calculations to  make them more accurate.

A lot of study in mathematics and physics is needed to be able to understand the present model of particle physics interactions.

Comment: Wikipedia is junk and since axions are the particles that let the energy flash happen  between particles and their anti-particle nobody really knows if they do, kind of like that neutrino thing

Comment: It makes no sense yet it does at the same time though

Comment: Wikipedia is not junk, it is for most physics an easy introduction for people who are not into the mathematics of physics. "Energy flashes" you imagine are science fiction. **There are no energy flashes defined in mainstream physics vocabulary for particle physics.**

Comment: just a hint : for smar middle t schoolers  to become smart physicist a lot of elbow grease is needed, knowledge is not automatic.

Comment: I know and the flash I was referring to was the energy flash created when a particle meets its anti-particle

Comment: @PeterBarendt Only at low energies only photons come out when electron hits a postiron, for higher energies a whole  ensemble  of new particle antiparticle pairshappen, and also other particles as long as the quantum numbers of the total add up to zero.For antiproton meeting proton, even with low energy, because of the masses, and the strong interaction, the probability of photons is low, pions and kaons are produced in +- pairs, plus some neutrals.

Comment: http://inspirehep.net/record/1341362/files/C60-08-25-p164.pdf

Comment: thanks for the answer