# Why there is no reaction Deuterium + Deuterium $=\rm {}^{4}He$?

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, fusion, binding-energy

Why there is no reaction like

$D+D={}^{4}He$

specified [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_power#Deuterium) and in other places like this?

Apparently

$2\times2.0141-4.0026=0.0256$

is positive. What is the problem with this reaction?

Comment: [Closely related, possible duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111707/44126).

Answer (score 14):

According to Krane's *Introduction to Nuclear Physics* (Chapter 14), the reaction
$$
D + D \to {}^4\mathrm{He} + \gamma
$$
is possible but rare.  The gamma ray is necessary because (as you note) there is energy released in the reaction, and it has to go somewhere.  However, the $Q$-value for this reaction (23.8 MeV) is greater than either the neutron or proton separation energy for helium-4, and so the reactions $D + D \to {}^3 \mathrm{H} + p$ or $D + D \to {}^3 \mathrm{He} + n$ are more likely.

The likelihood of this reaction actually occurring is discussed in

> Wilkinson & Cecil, "<sup>2</sup>H(d,$\gamma$)<sup>4</sup>He reaction at low energies." [Phys. Rev. **C31**, 2036 (1985)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevC.31.2036)

and references therein.  Figure 5 of that article shows branching ratios for the $D + D \to {}^4\mathrm{He} + \gamma$ reaction of between $10^{-4}$ to $10^{-7}$, depending on the energy.  (These branching ratios are calculated relative to the $D + D \to {}^3 \mathrm{H} + p$ reaction.)  In other words, this reaction is somewhere between ten thousand and ten million times less frequent than the reaction in which a proton is released.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand the resulting $^4He$ is highly excited and immediately splits into either $^3He$ and a neutron or $^3H$ and a proton.

Probably this is due to the fact that (in the center of mass frame) the resulting $^4He$ is at rest and thus the excess energy cannot be transferred into kinetic energy and thus has to stay inside the $^4He$ nucleus as excitation energy. By splitting into two parts, which can carry away some of the excess energy in form of kinetic energy, the nuclei can stabilize.